# WebApp accessing external customers Google Ad Campaigns

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I'm trying to build a web application in ASP.NET Core MVC with C# where I can provide some benefit for Google Ad customers. I am struggeling with the part on how do I get access to the customers Ads Account Data through the Google Ads API.

What I figured out so far

- My Application needs to be [registered with Google, having an OAuth Screen](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/get-started/oauth-cloud-project) (with the scope of Google Ads API), providing a ClientId and a Secret
- I need a developer token to access the API
- A Test Google Ad Account to not mess around with any live Ad Campaigns.

I got the OAuth ClientID and Secret, have managed to [declare and setup the ASP.NET Core Identity for Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-8.0), and I am able to register in my local WebApp with a Google Account and the Login is also working.

Is the API Token to be generated by my Google for my Application, e.g. would I need a Google Ads account for my Application itself
OR do I need from each of my customers a API Token to access their data?
Or is there a different way to access the customers Google Ads Campaign info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles about this question as well. I had to create a new Google Ads Manager Account which is to be "used" by my Application through the API Token generated from there. In this new Ads Manager Account I can [link customer accounts](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7459601?hl=en). Obivously the customer is getting an invitation and can accept/cancel the request.